# ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject can this be used to create Objects for our customeapplication

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, comautomationfactory

Can `ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject` be used to create an `IDisposable` object for our COM application?  If possible, what value should be given as `ProgramID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Here is one way you can do it: http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/441/Silverlight-and-Desktop-NET-Integration.aspx